# Android Simple ListFragment using SQLite

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-sqlite, android-listfragment

I am trying to create a simple ListFragment, I have run it successfully using a standard list activity but I am now trying to implement it using ListFragments.

What I am trying to do is display the SQLite data in the Listfragment. How do I pass ListNotes to Notes fragment?

```
public class Notes extends Fragment {

NotesControl control;
DatabaseHelper help;
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notes, container, false);

    Cursor cursor = control.ListNotes();
    //Mapping the fields cursor to text views
    String[] fields = new String[]{help.COLUMN_TITLE, help.COLUMN_DATE};
    int [] text = new int[] {R.id.item_title, R.id.item_date};
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(view.getContext(),R.layout.list_layout,cursor, fields, text);
    ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;
}
```

NotesControl

```
public Cursor ListNotes() {

}
```

How can I query this? Where can I store DB data to pass back to my listview ?

Comment: A custom adapter would be a good way to start...

Comment: @jvrodrigues NotesControl holds all my query towards the database, what will my custom adapter hold? would I need another xml file? do you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `SimpleCursorAdapter` :

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
        cursor, 
        new String[] { help.COLUMN_TITLE }, 
        new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Only thing is that you need a id column with the name "_id" on your cursor for it to work, so either change the column name, or do a `rawQuery()` with 'SELECT ' + help.NOTES_ID +  ' AS _id ...'

Comment: Can you write out the full query please? Will this go onto my onCreateView or onActivityCreated? From the code, will this only return the title but not the description? Would I need a custom adapter to dispay the discription

Comment: you can create any layout for the list items and use it instead of android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1. The String array takes the columns of the cursor and in the int[] array you put the ids of the views from the layout you created to put the columns you selected.

There are many tutorials on the subject on the web and on stackoverflow, just google simplecursoradapter .